# Unable to install the app in simulator by running the 'react-native run-ios' after upgrading to 0.61.5

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

Unable to install the app in simulator by running the 'react-native run-ios' after upgrading to 0.61.5

Getting the following error

```
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=2):
Failed to install the requested application
An application bundle was not found at the provided path.
Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle.
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist
error Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/App.app/Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist
. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/App.app/Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:574:11)
    at Object.execFileSync (child_process.js:592:13)
    at runOnSimulator (node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/build/commands/runIOS/index.js:183:45)
    at <anonymous>
```